# Why not using events instead of state variables, for requests to oracles?

Tags: events, ethereum, solidity

Why not just emit events instead of using state variables, for requests to oracles? For example:

```
contract OracleConsumer {
  address oracle = 0x123...; // known account of oracle service
  
  modifier onlyBy(address account) { 
    require(msg.sender == account);  _; 
  }

  event OracleRequest(..., abi encoding of callback function )
  
  function updateExchangeRate() {
    event OracleRequest("USD", ..., "oracleResponse(bytes)" )
  }
    
  function oracleResponse(bytes response) onlyBy(oracle) { 
    // use the data
  }
}
```

Instead of ones like in [here](https://github.com/maxwoe/solidity_patterns/tree/master/action_and_control/oracle)

Comment: One benefit of using different contracts is the contacts can be updated without affecting the contract calling them. If you use an event in your current contract, you cannot update it at a later time without updating your whole contract.

Comment: The point here is making external service know of a callback function by passing the encoding of the callback function on event parameter; instead of storing it in state variables as in link. So, using seperate contract is irrelevant in this point. Thanks for your comment, I 'm gonna add more indicators in question related to this.